# Spring AOP - Applying Introduction to POJO

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am creating a Spring Boot application and trying to use Spring AOP [Introductions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#introductions) to assign an interface and implementation to a class. However, currently, after instantiating the object, it doesn't seem to have the interface applied.

I am new to AOP - is it because I am not creating the class from the application context - if so, this seems fairly limiting.

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ResourceIdentification Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ResourceIdentification {

    @DeclareParents(value="com.example.Greeting*", defaultImpl=AbstractResource.class)
    public Resource mixin;

}
```

Controller - For demonstration purposes.

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Resource greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

        Resource greeting = (Resource) new Greeting(String.format(template, name));

        return greeting;
     }
}
```

My understand is that the Greeting class now implements the Resource interface (using AbstractResource). However, I get a ClassCastException.

In addition, I would expect to see something in the logs during startup to indicate that my Aspect has been found and applied, however, the logs don't show anything to do with AOP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work and will never work. Spring AOP only works for Spring Managed objects, you are constructing objects yourself hence AOP will simply not apply. You will have to use a full blown AOP solution to make it work (either load or compile time weaving). Another tip use `spring-boot-starter-aop` instead of declaring AspectJ (and a very old version!) yourself.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum - I thought that might be the case. FYI - If I remove the AspectJ weaver library and instead add spring-boot-starter-aop, none of my AspectJ annotations are recognised. Do I need AspectJ weaver too?

Comment: This is odd. I can see it in my dependency heirarchy after I include the aop starter and I can see it in the Javadocs for the associated version. But, I get a BUILD FAILURE.